# How to show subcategory name of a post in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have Main Category - Sub Category 1 - Sub Category 2 - Child Category .

If i click the child category , using the following script i can sort the post.

`<?php if (have_posts()) : $i = 0; while (have_posts()) : $i++; the_post(); ?>`

To show the category name i use ,

`$category = get_the_category();$category->cat_name;`

But i can't show the sub category and child category so please help me!.

Answer (score 2):

This will print only sub category and not a parent

```
<?php
       $cat_name = 'category';
       $categories = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $cat_name );
       foreach($categories as $category) {
         if($category->parent){
            echo $category->name;
         }
       }  
?>
```

Comment: Yes. It's working good. If you would like to add a link to the displayed category just add
                if($category->parent){
                    $category = get_term_link( $category );     
                    echo "<a href='". $category ."'>Link</a>";          
                }

Answer (score 0):

Check out settings for this in the wordpress codex here

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories

Right now you are only calling for the main categories but not the children, this should help depending on what exactly you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();  
    $category = get_the_category();
    //var_export( $category[0] ); // All info about this post's category
    echo $category[0]->cat_name; // will print the category/sub-category name
?>
```

Make sure that in the post itself, the sub-category is checked but not the parent.

*(sometimes it doesn't work if both are "checked")*